# Java conditional statement/ initializing variable

Tags: java

Currently this is my code, and I need to display " Please enter a valid choice" when the user don't pick A,B,C,D,E or F as their choices. The problem is if I put the statement " Please enter a valid...." on the "else" conditional, Java would ask me to initialized the variable ActivityFactor as there will not be one if the user don't select the correct choice. Anyone know how I can fix this? Or any idea how I should code a program to do such?

```
if((inGender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") ||(inGender.equalsIgnoreCase ("F"))) && inActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
            ActivityFactor = 1.0;

        else if ((inGender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") ||(inGender.equalsIgnoreCase ("F"))) && inActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        ActivityFactor = 1.3;

        else if (inGender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && inActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
        ActivityFactor = 1.6;
        else if (inGender.equalsIgnoreCase("F") && inActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
        ActivityFactor = 1.5;
        else if (inGender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && inActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
        ActivityFactor = 1.7;
        else if (inGender.equalsIgnoreCase("F") && inActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
        ActivityFactor = 1.6;
        else if (inGender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && inActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("E"))
        ActivityFactor = 2.1;
        else if (inGender.equalsIgnoreCase("F") && inActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("E"))
        ActivityFactor = 1.9;
        else if (inGender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && inActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
        ActivityFactor = 2.4;
        else if (inGender.equalsIgnoreCase("F") && inActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
        ActivityFactor = 2.2;
        else
        {
       ActivityFactor = -1;

    }

    //After
    if(ActivityFactor != -1){
     tdee = (nBMR * ActivityFactor);
     System.out.println(tdee);}
    else
   { System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialise ActivityFactor to an usual value before your conditional.

For example you may do this:

```
// knowing that it can never be -1
// so if that value remains, you know that user entered wrong letter
ActivityFactor = -1

// then the conditional begins
if((inGender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") ||(inGender.equalsIgnoreCase ("F"))) && inActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
...

// after conditional...
if(activityFactor != -1){
    double TDEE = (nBMR * ActivityFactor);
}
```

By the way, I suggest you use 'activityFactor' instead of ActivityFactor.

Comment: If I initialized it to -1 wouldn't it still carry out the  double TDEE = (nBMR * ActivityFactor);? Thanks

Comment: before carrying that out test if it's equal to -1, if it is then don't carry it out. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you!Can you look at my code again and tell me if it similar to what you're talking about ?

Comment: yes that's similar. The idea is this, the value -1 works as an error code. That should work for now I bet. Eventually, you'll learn to do it in other interesting ways.

Comment: This is very much creating a later (and identical) problem to solve an immediate one. **This will create problems if you're going to later rely on TDEE though - you'll be back to square one as TDEE wont be initialised/exist**. Much better solution is to get valid input prior to continuing execution.

Comment: I'm sure he has taken note of the other comments. One step at a time... @user1906857 you may optionally throw an exception if the user enters a wrong character. Or you can put that block of conditional in a loop that continues until activityFactor != -1.

Comment: Thank you for the reply guys. It just I'm limit to using if/else if/ else only that why. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 2):

If non of the conditions in the if statements is true, then you don't assign anything to `ActivityFactor`, and it is not initialized when used in the line `double TDEE = (nBMR * ActivityFactor);`.

Either initialize it before the code you've shown here, give it a default value in the last case, or loop until you get a valid value.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give me an idea on how to create a program where the user is asked to ender their gender, and BMR. Then select a choice of activity ( From A to F, each choice assign a different activity factor), if the user don't select a valid choice, then display " Please enter a valid choice" and if they do enter a valid choice, the factor is * with the bmr. Thanks

Comment: Even if one of the conditions in the if-else statement is true, you can't know it before hand. `ActivityFactor` won't be considered initialized and the code won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Either initialize your variable before the loop, or place the whole loop inside a function and then do something like:

```
double TDEE = (nBMR * getActivityFactor());
```

Also, have a look at this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

happy coding! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should do two things:

1. Enclose the logic in method
2. Throw an exception if argument do not match the method logic.

You can solve this problem throwing an exception that you will catch.

```
private double getTDEE (String inGender, String inActivity) {

   //logic
   else {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please enter a valid choice");
   }

  return (nBMR * ActivityFactor);
}
```

[Exception tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Answer (score 0):

As you're already aware, the problem with your code is that execution continues regardless of whether the user has entered valid input. Due to this, much refactoring is due - I would also attempt to make the conditional statements a little bit prettier; but that's personal preference.

Possible solutions:

**a) Use a loop** - Then break out of the loop when the user has entered satisfactory input..

```
while( true ){ 
   /* get input from the user */

   /* run through validation checks... 
        and -break- out of the loop when they're satisfied */
}
/* do calculations here */
```

**b) Use a function** to abstract all this logic away.. (as [Psyclops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13897183/1475897) suggests)

Personally, I would use a combination of these approaches - have all of this logic extracted away in to a function which returns false when no valid input is entered, and then use a construct like `while(! yourFunction() )` to simply loop through it until it's completed. You could using *passing by reference* to avoid having to use the return type for anything other than a boolean value.

**I wouldnt initialise the variable before the loop!** This just means the programme will continue to execute; however it wont have any appropriate data in there - which is potentially worse than the application just crashing.

I haven't exactly gifted you the answer in code - but hopefully it's a starting point to allow you to think about how to conceptually compose/design such a solution. That's generally the hardest part.. ;) Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! When you say to make the conditional statement prettier, could you tell me how?

Comment: @user1906857 - actually that may have been a mistake on my end, as I was viewing this post on my phone! I generally avoid long conditional structures like that though, preferring to generate some form of alternate solution - perhaps with the use of an enumeration etc. That really is personal preference though.